# XmlDocument C# получить элемент и удалить его

Tags: c#, xml

Всем привет.
Подскажите часть кода, пожалуйста, с помощью которой можно получить значения нужных элементов из XML документа с содержимым:

```
<doc>
    <elem>content</elem>
    <items>
        <item attr1="1" attr2="s" attr3="s" />
        <item attr1="2" attr2="s" attr3="s" />
        <item attr1="3" attr2="s" attr3="s" />
    </items>
</doc>
```

Каким образом я смогу получить доступ к содержимому  и в цикле к элементам "item"?
Причем, элемента "elem" нужно получить содержимое единожды, а "item"'ы планирую сохранить в объект и в дальнейшем получать содержимое самого первого элемента, работать с ним, а в последствии удалять его из памяти в объекте и снова получать содержимое самого первого элемента, пока объект не станет пустым (как к массиву).

Comment: Даже не в цикле, а просто получать самый первый элемент "item", а потом удалять его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто. Вот вам пример. Пусть `doc` содержит ваш `XmlDocument`. Нужные узлы легко получить используя XPath:

```
// получаем текст из content:
var content = doc.SelectSingleNode("/doc/elem/text()").Value;
Console.WriteLine(content);
// получаем все item'ы
var items = doc.SelectNodes("/doc/items/item");
foreach (XmlElement item in items)
{
    // здесь вы можете обрабатывать текущий item
    Console.Write("item:");
    foreach (XmlAttribute attr in item.Attributes)
        Console.Write($" {attr.Name} = {attr.Value}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Это выдаёт такой текст:

```
content
item: attr1 = 1 attr2 = s attr3 = s
item: attr1 = 2 attr2 = s attr3 = s
item: attr1 = 3 attr2 = s attr3 = s
```

Answer (score 1):

Через LINQ to XML это делается вот так:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);

List<XElement> items = doc.Root.Element("items").Elements("item").ToList();
```

Теперь `items` - список нужных вам элементов из файла, с которым вы можете делать что вам требуется.

Comment: Ну у автора в заголовке `XmlDocument`.

Comment: @VladD ну, надо же было написать что-нибудь в противовес тому ужасу из другого ответа. А то его автор даже не понимает что именно сделал неправильно...

Comment: Окей, согласен. Перебор всех элементов — это _перебор_.

Comment: А, там не перебор всех, а for/if вместо выбора по имени.

Comment: @VladD так это еще хуже. Ладно бы алгоритм был переборный - так ведь алгоритм нормальный, но создается впечатление что так и надо писать...

Comment: Да, настоящий антипаттерн. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793

Answer (score -1):

Можно еще через LINQ to XML:

```
const string fileName = @"C:\Users\admin\Documents\item.xml";

// Загружаем файл
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

// Проходим по всем корневым элементам
foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    // Тут какие-то действия с ними
    if (el.Name == "items")
    {
        // Перебираем дочерний элементы узла "items"
        foreach (XElement item in el.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            // Перебираем все атрибуты элемента
            foreach (XAttribute attr in item.Attributes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/24673/) по этому поводу на Хабре.

Comment: Зачем плохому учите? Вот в чем смысл делать цикл по всем элементам только для того чтобы найти среди них "items"?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov смысл в вопросе. `"elem" нужно получить содержимое единожды, а "item"'ы планирую сохранить в объект и в дальнейшем получать содержимое самого первого элемента`. Не совсем явно указано, какое содержимое нужно, поэтому для наглядности в коде показано как добраться до атрибутов элемента.

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, мой прошлый комментарий еще раз. Вы не ответили на него.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov не вижу ничего плохого в использовании циклов. Код просто показывает как использовать `LINQ to XML`. Можно и напрямую обратиться к любому узлу.

Comment: Вот, VladD нашел замечальную статью как раз про ваш случай: http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793